# Reason that SSD read speed very low when moving large files out of SSD on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssd

The device is WDS100T2B0A.

Western Digital Dashboard show the wear as 4%.

Windows 10 is smooth. But when moving large files such as .vmdk files out of the SSD, the read speed is only ~2MB/s, and the system become sluggish. It is so sluggish that opening a web page in Chrome take 10 seconds.

Maybe the reason is .vmdk is highly fragmented, but the point of SSD is good random reading performance. So a file read making the system sluggish is not normal at all considering the system should have a good disk I/O QoS system to satisfy system I/O need first.

So after moving all data from SSD to HDD after a disastrous data loss on SSD, I'm also moving VM system disks from SSD to HDD, only left Windows 10 on SSD...

So what could be the reason, is there a way to find out why?

Comment: I don’t have an answer. I use a Samsung drive and can copy a whole folder of virtual machines (150GB) as fast as wireless will go (AC wireless) . So the issue is not Windows or SSD (unless your specific SSD )

Comment: File fragmentation is basically nonexistent or if it does exist it doesn’t affect system performance. The type of performance you are getting suggests the problem is linked to the fact it’s a SATA drive..